# How to change website dynamically after HTTP POST request

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, http-post, hook

I have been trying to change the homepage dynamically after a form submission, but I can't see why it's not working.

What I need is to redirect users after they choose and submit some fields in the form and send those fields with HTTP POST to another page. If certain fields were submitted, the whole links on the website will change to match with the new submit.

Below is what I have till now. I'm using contact form 7 to build the form (this form is in the homepage):

```
<div class="home-form">
<div id="region">[select* your-region id:region "Choose a region" "North America" "Latin America" "Europa"]</div>

<div id="language">[select* your-idiom id:language "Choose a language" "Español" "English"]</div>

<div class="submitbutton"><a href="">Go to page</a></div>

</div>
```

Also, I have to set a correct action for this POST to be sent to the page I want, so I add this to functions.php:

```
//CHANGING ACTION URL
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $post;
    $id_to_change = $pageid;
    if($post->ID === $id_to_change)
        return 'https://website.com/na/';
    else
        return $url;
}
```

To get the HTTP POST, I just use this function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_home_form' ); 

function get_home_form( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

   if ( 'Home selection' == $title ) {

        $region = $posted_data['your-region'];
        $idiom = $posted_data['your-idiom'];
    }
}
```

Till now, this is not working. I see so many times on the Google networks tool on the development tool, to check if the form has been sent to POST and it's not. I don't see the request.

Also, if I try to make and 'echo' to check if I can capture the "your-region" input and display it, it's not working too.

Comment: Limit this question to _one question_, please.  Please edit your question to isolate a single issue, per StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: it is ok right now @cale_b ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know PHP so I can't help you with problem 1.

With problem 2, I would suggest having two separate divs in your client HTML.
The first div with your main page, and the second div with  your new content you want to show.

```
<div id="main-page">Content of main page.</div>

<div id="sub-page">Content of sub page.</div>
```

In CSS, set your second div to "display: none;" to hide it.

```
#sub-page {
  display: none;
}
```

When you need to switch views, use Javascript or JQuery to toggle the display back to "display: block;" as desired. (Also don't forget to toggle the first div).

```
var button = document.querySelector("#change-view-button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var mainPage = document.querySelector("#main-page");
  var subPage = document.querySelector("#sub-page");

  if (mainPage.style.display !== "none") {
    mainPage.style.display = "none";
    subPage.style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
    mainPage.style.display = "block";
    subPage.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Working example:
https://codepen.io/vck3000/pen/qxQNBp

Comment: It's not recommended to answer a "WordPress" question when you don't know WordPress nor PHP....

Comment: I didn't see it being a WordPress question, only noticed it mentioned in a tag afterwards (no other mention). Sorry.